# MacOS Big Sur refuses to connect LAN

Tags: networking, macos, macos-bigsur

I have this one computer (Mac Mini M1 / Big Sur) that refuses to connect to other computers on the same local network. My question is (1) why is this happening, (2) how to fix it (3) how to prevent this from happening?

Details are as below ↓↓↓

Let's say this computer has IP `192.168.2.6`, and let's consider another, non-problematic computer, at `192.168.2.26`.
From `.26` I can ping `.6`, but from `.6` I cannot ping `.26` (or anything else on the LAN); it says:

```
[192.168.2.6] $> ping 192.168.2.26
PING 192.168.2.26 (192.168.2.26): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
```

An ARP command on .6 gives me:

```
[192.168.2.6] $> arp -a
? (192.168.2.1) at 90:6c:ac:2e:5f:51 on en1 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.2.6) at 14:98:77:60:3d:15 on en1 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (224.0.0.251) at 1:0:5e:0:0:fb on en1 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
```

As you can see, `192.168.2.26` was not added to the cache.

Now if I check the routing tables (I hide the Internet6 section):

```
[192.168.2.6] $> netstat -rn                                      
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Netif Expire
default            192.168.2.1        UGScg          en1       
127                127.0.0.1          UCS            lo0       
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             lo0       
169.254            link#12            UCS            en1      !
192.168.2.1/32     link#12            UCS            en1      !
192.168.2.1        90:6c:ac:2e:5f:51  UHLWIir        en1   1191
192.168.2.4/32     link#12            UCS            en1      !
192.168.2.6/32     link#12            UCS            en1      !
192.168.2.6        14:98:77:60:3d:15  UHLWI          lo0       
224.0.0/4          link#12            UmCS           en1      !
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI         en1       
255.255.255.255/32 link#12            UCS            en1      !

[192.168.2.6] $> netstat -rni
Name       Mtu   Network       Address            Ipkts Ierrs    Opkts Oerrs  Coll
lo0   16384 <Link#1>                        324332     0   324332     0     0
lo0   16384 127           127.0.0.1         324332     -   324332     -     -
lo0   16384 ::1/128     ::1                 324332     -   324332     -     -
lo0   16384 fe80::1%lo0 fe80:1::1           324332     -   324332     -     -
gif0* 1280  <Link#2>                             0     0        0     0     0
stf0* 1280  <Link#3>                             0     0        0     0     0
anpi1 1500  <Link#4>    1e:00:d9:36:56:42        0     0        0     0     0
anpi1 1500  fe80::1c00: fe80:4::1c00:d9ff        0     -        0     -     -
anpi0 1500  <Link#5>    1e:00:d9:36:56:41        0     0        0     0     0
anpi0 1500  fe80::1c00: fe80:5::1c00:d9ff        0     -        0     -     -
en0   1500  <Link#6>    14:98:77:5f:54:8b        0     0        0     0     0
en4   1500  <Link#7>    1e:00:d9:36:56:21        0     0        0     0     0
en5   1500  <Link#8>    1e:00:d9:36:56:22        0     0        0     0     0
en5   1500  fe80::489:2 fe80:8::489:219d:        0     -        0     -     -
en2   1500  <Link#9>    36:da:2b:5c:28:c0        0     0        0     0     0
en3   1500  <Link#10>   36:da:2b:5c:28:c4        0     0        0     0     0
ap1*  1500  <Link#11>   36:98:77:60:3d:15        0     0        0     0     0
en1   1500  <Link#12>   14:98:77:60:3d:15   406922     0   734702    43     0
en1   1500  fe80::cb8:8 fe80:c::cb8:8b8c:   406922     -   734702     -     -
en1   1500  192.168.2     192.168.2.6       406922     -   734702     -     -
bridg 1500  <Link#13>   36:da:2b:5c:28:c0        0     0        0     0     0
awdl0 1500  <Link#14>   46:42:be:eb:5d:08        0     0        6     0     0
awdl0 1500  fe80::4442: fe80:e::4442:beff        0     -        6     -     -
llw0  1500  <Link#15>   46:42:be:eb:5d:08        0     0        0     0     0
llw0  1500  fe80::4442: fe80:f::4442:beff        0     -        0     -     -
utun0 1380  <Link#16>                            0     0        2     0     0
utun0 1380  fe80::8ef4: fe80:10::8ef4:c50        0     -        2     -     -
utun1 2000  <Link#17>                            0     0        2     0     0
utun1 2000  fe80::a9c3: fe80:11::a9c3:e01        0     -        2     -     -
```

When comparing with a healthy computer with a same configuration, I noticed the following default routes are missing:

- to the subnet `192.168.2`, e.g. (copied from a healthy computer)

```
192.168.2          link#18            UCS            en5      !
192.168.2          link#12            UCSI           en0      !
```

- to other computers in the networks, e.g. (copied from a healthy computer)

```
192.168.2.19       50:32:37:ea:56:8   UHLWI          en5     13
```

I have tried to:

- add static routes on `.6` to other computers. The route appears in `netstat -rn` but none of the symptom disappear

```
[192.168.2.6] $> sudo route add -host 192.168.2.6/32 -interface en1
```

- flush many times the routing tables, but no luck either

```
[192.168.2.6] $> sudo route -n flush
```

- reboot, disconnect and reconnect the network interface

Notes:

- I can access the Internet from `.6`:

```
[192.168.2.6] $> ping www.google.com                                
PING www.google.com (142.250.206.228): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 142.250.206.228: icmp_seq=0 ttl=57 time=20.794 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.206.228: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=28.699 ms
```

- `.6` can ping itself

```
[192.168.2.6] $> ping 192.168.2.6
PING 192.168.2.6 (192.168.2.6): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.2.6: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.095 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.6: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.140 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.6: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.121 ms
```

- I can ssh from `.26` to `.6`, but not from `.6` to `.26`.
  Even better, I noticed that some machines (e.g. `192.168.0.19`) on my network cannot even ssh at all to `.6` (I cannot ssh from `.6` to any machine on the LAN, including `.26` and `.19`. Ping and SSH between any other machine on the LAN works fine)

```
[192.168.2.19] $> ssh -p 22 192.168.2.6
ssh: connect to host 192.168.2.6 port 22: Operation timed out
```

Comment: Any chance you've got a VPN configured/running on .6? A full-tunnel VPN will intentionally try to keep you from talking directly to other devices on your LAN, in case your LAN is an untrusted public Wi-Fi.

Comment: Well we never installed any VPN on this machine, but maybe someone tried and left some broken bits on the machine. The output of `scutil --nc list` is empty. Is there other way to look for processes that are messing with my routing table?